# How do I change the package and Email on Play Console?

Tags: android, google-developers-console, google-account

I have an a developer account on Google Play Console with couple of apps. The thing is I would like to change the email and the package name. My email is (let's say) **myemail**@gmail.com and the package name of all my apps is com.**myemail**.appname. I would like to create a new Account with a different name, also, transfer all my apps to the new account and also, change the package names without losing current users (as Downloads).

Is that possible?

Comment: You can transfer apps between accounts.  Changing the package name is probably a no go though, the package name is how the store and phones determine the identity of an app.  Changing the name of the app is possible, but if your app is com.example.myapp,  you may be stuck with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Ok, clear, but if I will change the package name to a different name, let's say, for  a new app, that would work, because the package name does not have to do with Account (and email), right?